# PostgreSQL accent + case insensitive search

Tags: postgresql, database-design, indexing, full-text-search, case-insensitive

I'm looking for a way to support with good performances case insensitive + accent insensitive search. Till now we had no issue on this using MSSql server, on Oracle we had to use `OracleText`, and now we need it on PostgreSQL.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216) about it, but we need to combine it with case insensitive. We also need to use indexes, otherwise performances could be impacted.
Any real experience about the best approach for large databases?

Comment: Did you check the full text search functions in PostgreSQL? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html

Comment: The upcoming PostgreSQL 10 release will add support for this via ICU Collation Support. http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2017/04/new-features-coming-in-postgresql-10.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to "combine with case insensitive", there are a number of options, depending on your exact requirements.

Maybe simplest, make the expression index case insensitive.

Building on the function `f_unaccent()` laid out in the referenced answer:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

```
CREATE INDEX users_lower_unaccent_name_idx ON users(lower(f_unaccent(name)));
```

Then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  lower(f_unaccent(name)) = lower(f_unaccent('João'));
```

**Or** you could build the `lower()` into the function `f_unaccent()`, to derive something like `f_lower_unaccent()`.

**Or** (especially if you need to do fuzzy pattern matching anyways) you can use a trigram index provided by the additional module [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) building on above function, which also supports `ILIKE`. Details:

- [LOWER LIKE vs iLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336665/lower-like-vs-ilike/20337500#20337500)

I added a note to the [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860).

**Or** you *could* use the additional module [`citext`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html) (but I rather avoid it):

- [Deferrable, case-insensitive unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905867/deferrable-case-insensitive-unique-constraint/16907381#16907381)

Comment: that's quite a good list of hint to look into.  Our requrements are "simple" in theory:if a column contains let's say Firstname = “Aloïse”, we want to be able to find the row using for instance: "Aloise"  or "aloise" or even "lois".

Answer (score 5):

### Full-Text-Search Dictionary that Unaccent case-insensitive

[FTS is naturally case-insensitive by default,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-DOCUMENT)

> Converting tokens into lexemes. A lexeme is a string, just like a token, but it has been normalized so that different forms of the same word are made alike. For example, **normalization almost always includes folding upper-case letters to lower-case**, and often involves removal of suffixes (such as s or es in English).

And you can define your own dictionary using `unaccent`,

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mydict ( COPY = simple );
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mydict
  ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word
  WITH unaccent, simple;
```

Which you can then index with a functional index,

```
-- Just some sample data...
CREATE TABLE myTable ( myCol )
  AS VALUES ('fóó bar baz'),('qux quz');

-- No index required, but feel free to create one
CREATE INDEX ON myTable
  USING GIST (to_tsvector('mydict', myCol));
```

You can now query it very simply

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE to_tsvector('mydict', myCol) @@ 'foo & bar'

    mycol    
-------------
 fóó bar baz
(1 row)
```

See also

- [Creating a case-insensitive and accent/diacritics insensitive search on a field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177044/2639)

Comment: Very clean solution. Works great.