# How to make diacritics insensitive queries in PostgreSQL, without unaccent extension?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, diacritics, unaccent

I need to do queries ignoring diacritics (and case) in PostgreSQL 9.3. Everything I've found about it (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11005036/1086511), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28627951/1086511) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/177020/70100)) requires the installation of the `unaccent` extension. However, I cannot have it installed on my server.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Upgrade to a recent version and use case and accent insensitive ICU collations, which you can define yourself. If you cannot upgrade, and you cannot install an extension, you have to accept that you are too limited to get what you want.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I guess you mean PostgreSQL 12?

Comment: Technically yes, but at this point it would be silly to upgrade to anything less than v13, and I would recommend v14.