# In PostgreSQL, weird issue about citext performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/citext.html) it says that `citext` is simply a module that implements `TEXT` data type with a call to `LOWER()`:

> The citext module provides a case-insensitive character string type,
>   citext. Essentially, it internally calls lower when comparing values.
>   Otherwise, it behaves almost exactly like text.

On the other hand at the end of the documntation it says:

> citext is not as efficient as text because the operator functions and
>   the B-tree comparison functions must make copies of the data and
>   convert it to lower case for comparisons. It is, however, slightly
>   more efficient than using lower to get case-insensitive matching.

So I'm confused if it uses `LOWER()` how can it be "slightly more efficient than using lower"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't call the SQL function `lower`. As the documentation says, it *essentially* *internally* calls `lower`.

The calls happen within the C functions which implement the `citext` comparison operations. And rather than actually calling `lower`, they go directly to the underlying `str_tolower()` routine. You can see this for yourself in the [source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/aa9eac45ea868e6ddabc4eb076d18be10ce84c6a/contrib/citext/citext.c#L113), most of which is relatively easy to follow in this case.

So what you're saving, more or less, is the overhead of two SQL function calls per comparison. Which is not insignificant, compared with the cost of the comparison itself, but you'd probably never notice either of them next to the other costs in a typical query.

Comment: Just for completion: An index created on a citext colum only contains the lower case data. Thus the index will be much smaller. In queries the selector on citext columns will be converted to lower case once. Then for all the following comparisons the lower case index will be utilized. Thus the performance gain will be massive in comparison to using lower() in the query. Most of the boost comes from using the index effectively which is not possible with lower() queries.

Comment: @ Frankenstein: What about creating a `UNIQUE INDEX name_idx ON table (LOWER(name))` where `name` is a `text` column? Is it faster than an index on a `citext` column?