# PostgreSQL - citext perform than text for SELECT

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, sqlperformance, postgresql-performance

There are mentions regarding the performance issues in `citext` data type in PostgreSQL.[In PostgreSQL, weird issue about citext performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133603/in-postgresql-weird-issue-about-citext-performance). I wanted to measure actual performance difference in my scenario.

I have invite table and have used `(course_id, user_email)` as the primary key. So I converted the type of `user_email` to `citext`. Then ran automated tests to measure the difference between `text` and `citext`.

For insertion `citext` took more time than `text` as it suppose to get.

[image]

But for selecting data, `citext` actually took less time than `text`
[image]

I have posted all codes I used [here](https://gist.github.com/hddananjaya/5b9d567d00799e69552c53be82ced866). Can anyone explain this strange behavior? or have I missed something?

Thanks.